# How to send AJAX get request with reserved symbols in URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, get, air

Is there any client-side technology to send get request with unencoded query string?
I want to send some reserved symbols to server in URL without url encoding (eg. '>' or ']'). 
(I want to test server's behavior).

An XMLHttpRequest encodes these symbols automatically.
Maybe, it is possible by jQuery, or Flash, or something else?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now, I have the only one solution. We can send to the server ANY special character with the Java applet (even '\0'). Unfortunately, I didn't find this possibility in Flash and JS/JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

no it is not possible. the encoding is required as per the HTTP protocol specification if you want to send the special characters you are talking about.